# TypeError: errorbar() got multiple values for keyword argument 'yerr'

Tags: python, typeerror, multiple-value, errorbar

I am trying to plot errorbar with the array of mean values and standard deviation by python as below:

```
p11 = np.genfromtxt(filn1,delimiter="",usecols=0,dtype=None)
p12 = np.genfromtxt(filn3,delimiter="",usecols=0,dtype=None) 
s11 = np.genfromtxt(filn2,delimiter="",usecols=0,dtype=None)
s12 = np.genfromtxt(filn4,delimiter="",usecols=0,dtype=None)
F1= np.genfromtxt(filn6,delimiter="",usecols=0,dtype=None)
F2= np.genfromtxt(filn7,delimiter="",usecols=0,dtype=None)
yerr1 =0.5*s11
yerr2 = 0.5*s12
plt.errorbar(F1,p11,'r',yerr=yerr1,lw=3,label='Summer')
plt.errorbar(F2,p12,'b',yerr=yerr2,lw=3,label='Winter')
```

Here p11 and p12 are mean value arrays and s11 and s12 are corresponding standard deviation arrays.
This code has worked well, but now it resulted:

```
TypeError: errorbar() got multiple values for keyword argument 'yerr'
```

Any idea or hints would be really appreciated.
Isaac

Comment: What are those `r` and `b` values for?

Comment: @DanielRoseman 'r' and 'b' are for color.

Comment: Well, matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar does not appear to have color as the third positional argument: see [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=errorbar#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes Daniel Roseman, you are totally right. I apologize for my careless question.

Answer (score 6):

I think the third parameter for plt.errorbar has to be the yerr, but in your case you are using the format. Try to specify the format with 'fmt'.

```html
plt.errorbar(F1,p11,fmt='r',yerr=yerr1,lw=3,label='Summer')
plt.errorbar(F2,p12,fmt='b',yerr=yerr2,lw=3,label='Winter')
```

My advice is always use the parameter names, so it is easy to read the code and debugging.